# How to speed up a search in a long document using python?

Tags: python, list, search, vim, match

I was wondering if it is possible to search in Vim using Python in order to speed up a search in a long document.

I have a text document of 140.000 lines.
I have a list (mysearches) with 115 different search patterns.
I want to put all lines with matches in a list (hits)

This is what I do now:

```
 for i in range(0,len(mysearches)-1)

   for line in range(1, line("$"))
     let idx = match(getline(line), mysearches[i])
     if idx >= 0
       call add(hits, line)
     endif
   endfor
 endfor
```

"remove double linenumbers:

```
 let unduplist=filter(copy(hits), 'index(hits, v:val, v:key+1)==-1')
```

The problem is that this search takes over 5 minutes.
How can I adapt above search to a python search?

Comment: Where is Python here?

Comment: Better concatenate all patterns into one regexp (`foo\|bar\|baz\|...`), and use `call search(pattern, ...)` to let Vim itself iterate over the buffer, instead of doing the matching line by line.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I did this before but it gives a search url of many lines. Using "n" is very very slow. What I want to do is to collect all linenumbers and put a `'_'` before every line with a match and highlight the entire line. That why I need the linenumbers.

Comment: @georg, Vim is compiled with Python support.

Comment: There's a strong XY smell here. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I agree with comment from Ingo and romainl. I don't get your comment about using "n" - are you refering to `search()`'s flags? Why would you avoid moving the cursor? For romainl comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188334)

Comment: mMontu & romainl, maybe it is not clear in my question. I just want to have all linenumbers of matches in a list to speed up a search. I want to see all matches in my very big document and use 'n' to go to the next match. Inserting all search patterns in a single search code as Ingo proposed did not work well. No other goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
let pattern=join(mysearches, '\|')
let mylist = systemlist('grep -n "'.pattern.'" '. shellescape(fnamemodify(@%, ':p')). ' | cut -d: -f1')
```

This works by joining you pattern by `\|` (e.g. **OR**ing all your different patterns), shelling out and using `grep` to process your pattern. Grep should be pretty fast, a lot more than vim and possibly also faster than either python or even perl (of course this depends on the pattern).
The return value is a list, containing all matching lines. Since we used the `-n` switch of grep  we received the matching line numbers which were in turn cut out using `cut`.

`systemlist()` then contains the output split at `\n`.So mylist should contain all lines, matching your pattern. This of course depends on your pattern, but if you use standard BRE or ERE (-E) or even perl RE (-P switch) you should be okay. Depending on the flavor of RE desired, the joining part needs to be adjusted.

Note however this is basically untested, for a real robust solution, one would probably add some more error handling (possibly preprocessing of the pattern) and split up the whole part a little bit, so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be a very good solution. I sometimes use RE mostly VIM RE. I did a test in my document. Something is going wrong. I know there are 4 lines with matches. This is the output of mylist `['122^M', '14128^M']` Is it the shellescape? I'm working on a windows OS using Gvim.

Comment: It did not add two matches with `:` in the string.

Comment: Looks like the ^M are CR from Windows CR/LF line delimiter. Might be a bug there. if the pattern doesn't match, you need to carefully check if it is the correct pattern for grep. What is the pattern and what did not match?

Comment: Christian, pattern: `Rocket Singh: Salesman Of The Year` did not match the same text on line

Comment: Found it. Removed the cut: I cut the text now using matchstr `let hitstemp = systemlist('grep -in "'.pattern.'" '. shellescape(fnamemodify(@%, ':p')). '')  |    for i in range(0,len(hitstemp)-1) | call add(hits, matchstr(hitstemp[i], '^\d\+\ze')) |  endfor` The search is very very fast. 2 seconds in stead of 5 minutes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

XY problem indeed.

You can use the `:vimgrep` command like so:

```
execute "vim /\\(" . join(mysearches, "\\|") . "\\)/ %"
cwindow
```

I just tested with the the content of the 4017 lines-long `.less` file I'm working on, pasted 34 times into a new 136579 lines-long file and a list of only 13 searches:

```
:let foo = ["margin", "padding", "width", "height", "bleu", "gris", "none", "auto", "background", "color", "line", "border", "overflow"]
```

It took 3 seconds to find the 47634 matching lines which are now conveniently listed in the quickfix window.

YMMV, of course, because the search will take more time as you add items to `mysearches` and complexify them but I'm fairly sure you'll be able to beat your current timing easily.

You could also use `:grep`:

```
execute "grep -snH " . shellescape(join(foo, '\\|')) . " %"
```